# What's the best way to download multiple non-http downloads on android

Tags: java, android, download, task, p2p

I'm working on an p2p download apps and my goal is to have the best performance that i can get to download torrent files. I know that these download methods exist:

- Downloadmanager : only for httpdownload so i can't use this one
- AsyncTask : not made for long running download(or task)
- MultiThreading : this one could work (http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/create-threadpool.html)

what I need is to be able to have unlimited amount of downloads at the same time.

Any idea? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not http,  you will need to find a library that works ont he protocol you choose

- [ECF BitTorrent Provider](http://wiki.eclipse.org/ECF_BitTorrent_Provider)
- [apache commons ftp](http://commons.apache.org/net/)

As for setting up multithreading, you should defintely use the guava libraries to help create your ThreadPoolExecutors.  Its doubtful you will be able to get unlimited simultaneous downloads all happening at the same time, but you can queue a bunch of them.

here is the [User Guide for guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/GuavaExplained?tm=6)